# Google App Script: Run script from within another script?

Tags: google-apps-script, forms

I am working on a payroll web app for my company. I was wondering if there is anyway to run a script from within another script. Such as having a hyperlink or something similar that the user could go and see a different UI and everything. If this is not possible, does anyone knows how to submit a copy of a html form to an email? I been trying to do this but GAS removes the styles and the JavaScript code that fills the form before sending it. I just need at least an image of the form so the manager could print it out and sign it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can link from one script to another using regular anchors.

It's not Apps Script stripping your emailed form of this stuff. Email clients, including Gmail, intentionally don't support complex HTML. If you want an image, try creating a Google Doc with the DocumentsApp, converting it to pdf with document.getAs("application/pdf") and then emailing that.

Comment: I would like to try your solution but how do I evaluate the content of the form which is in HTML and convert it to a document? I'm using HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("form").evaluate().getContent() to get the content of the form